# Assigning return value of a function to multidimensional arrays in VHDL fails with Vivado

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I have the following package which defines a 2D array type and some random function which returns an initialized 2D array.

```
-- <matrix.vhd>
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

package matrix is     
    type matrix is array(integer range<>, integer range<>) of std_logic;
    function initmatrix(m: integer; n: integer) return matrix;
end package matrix;

package body matrix is
    
    function initmatrix(m: integer; n: integer) return matrix is
        variable a: matrix(m - 1 downto 0, n - 1 downto 0); 
    begin 
        for i in a'range(1) loop 
            for j in a'range(2) loop 
                if i = j then 
                    a(i, j) := '1';
                else 
                    a(i, j) := '0';
                end if;
            end loop;
        end loop;
        return a;
    end function initmatrix;
    
end package body matrix;
```

In the following example I try to assign the return value of the function initmatrix to a signal. This has some strange behaviour though.

```
-- <tb_test.vhd>
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use work.matrix.all;

entity tb_test is
end tb_test;

architecture x of tb_test is
    signal m: matrix(3 downto 0, 2 downto 0);
begin

    process 
        variable t: matrix(3 downto 0, 2 downto 0);
    begin
        m <= ("000", "000", "000", "000");  
        wait for 10 ns;
        
        -- This one does not work!
        -- results in ("000", 1UU", "UUU", "UUU")
        m <= initmatrix(4, 3);
        wait for 10 ns;
        
        -- This one does work!
        -- exactly the same as the function body
        for i in t'range(1) loop 
            for j in t'range(2) loop 
                if i = j then 
                    t(i, j) := '1';
                else
                    t(i, j) := '0';
                end if;
            end loop;
        end loop;
        m <= t;
        
        wait;
    end process;

end x;
```

The same construct (assigning the return value of a function to a signal) only seems to fail for multidimensional arrays. I do this all the time for any other type.

Am I overlooking something?

I am using Vivado 2020.2, have not tried any other simulator other than the one built into Vivado.

Comment: [You appear to have a tool issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8n10.jpg) or your [mcve] doesn't reproduce the problem.  ([The to_string function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efDgT.jpg))

Comment: Thank you for your comment. For me the problem persists, and the to_string() function shows the same, so I do appear to have a tool issue. Any idea what my issue might be? It looks like it's fine in synthesis, but that's useless if I can't verify my code through simulation.

Comment: I have resolved the issue. VHDL 2008 did the trick. I have no idea if this is a 2008 only thing or if XSim has a bug, but setting the files to 2008 resolved it. Answering my own question right now.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the Vivado simulator does not like unconstrained multidimensional arrays as a return type for functions, at least not for VHDL versions prior to 2008.

There is no issue with either unconstrained single dimensional arrays or constrained multi dimensional ones like these:

```
type vector is array(integer range <>) of std_logic;
type matrix4x3 is array(3 downto 0, 2 downto 0) of std_logic;
```

For correctly simulating the example in the question with Vivado, the file type of the source files needs to be set to VHDL 2008. Be aware that not all tools can fully handle VHDL 2008, and it is still not recommended to use this if you want your code to be portable.

Setting (all) source files to VHDL 2008 in Vivado is done with

```
set_property FILE_TYPE {VHDL 2008} [get_files *.vhd]
```

Comment: The multi-dimensional array type complies with IEEE Std 1076-1993 3.2.1 Array types, unconstrained array definitions, by your account unsupported in 2020.2 Vivado Simulator without -2008. IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.3.2 Array types changes unconstrained array definitions to unbounded array definitions and allows an object declaration to supply an unconstrained array element subtype with a constraint. Array indexes are treated identically to -1993. The simulator shares analysis with synthesis where multi-dimensional array support is relatively recent. You get what you pay for (it's no cost).