# VHDL variable length arrays without using access types

Tags: arrays, dynamic, vhdl

In synthesizable VHDL designs, I often need to do a few "software" calculations to convert high-level parameters (`generic`s) into low-level configurations. To do these calculations, it's useful to have basic software tools available, such as dynamic memory allocation.

To clarify, this parameter conversion usually takes the form of a `function` call that assigns a value to some `constant`, for example:

```vhdl
    constant internal_config_c  : config_t := calc_low_level_config(params_g);
```

Therefore, please note that this question is purely about VHDL "software" programming (the stuff that goes inside `calc_low_level_config`). My question is not about synthesis (the stuff that subsequently uses `internal_config_c`), and I only mention synthesis because Xilinx Vivado synthesis doesn't support `access` types, which to me would be the most natural way to create dynamic arrays in VHDL.

Therefore, my question is: **What programming constructs are available in VHDL (besides `access` types) for using (or mimicking) variable sized arrays?**

The only possible solution I have been able to come up with is recursion. I don't like this because I find recursive functions tend to be horribly unreadable, so I would be keen to learn about any alternatives.

To illustrate, here is a simplified but complete toy example using `access` types:

```vhdl
entity top is
generic (
    params_g    : integer_vector := (7, 11, 6)
);
end;

architecture rtl of top is
    
    function internal_calculations(x : natural) return bit_vector is
    begin
        -- Toy example...
        if x mod 3 = 2 then
            return "1101";
        elsif 7*x mod 5 < 3 then
            return (x-1 downto 0 => '1');
        else
            return (3*(x/2)-1 downto 0 => '0');
        end if;
    end function;
    
    function calc_low_level_config(params : integer_vector) return bit_vector is
        type ptr_t is access bit_vector;
        variable data   : ptr_t := new bit_vector'(0 to -1 => '0');
    begin
        -- Collect variable-length data
        for i in params'range loop
            data := new bit_vector'(data.all & internal_calculations(params(i)));
        end loop;
        
        -- Print
        report to_string(data.all);
        
        return data.all;
    end function;
    
    constant internal_config_c  : bit_vector := calc_low_level_config(params_g);
    
begin
end;
```

Simulating this in Modelsim prints out the expected result:

> vlib work 
> vcom -2008 top.vhd 
> vsim work.top 
> # ** Note: 0000000001101111111

However, the above implementation cannot be synthesized by Xilinx Vivado. Therefore, the only usable option I can think of is recursion, as shown below:

```vhdl
    function calc_low_level_config(params : integer_vector; idx : integer) return bit_vector is
    begin
        if idx = params'high then
            -- Exit condition
            return internal_calculations(params(idx));
        else
            -- Recurse
            return internal_calculations(params(idx)) & calc_low_level_config(params, idx+1);
        end if;
    end function;
    
    constant internal_config_c  : bit_vector := calc_low_level_config(params_g, params_g'low);
```

Is there a better way?

**EDIT**: In response to the initial comments below:

- The example code above is not intended for synthesis in a real project. I wrote it specifically to illustrate the type of array resizing I want to do. It is my attempt at a minimal but complete (compilable) example.
- I am not asking if array resizing is necessary in this hugely simplified example. My question about the VHDL language is primary and the example is very much secondary. Please ignore the example if it is a distraction.
- The real examples I have are complicated (involving multiple variable-length arrays inside the same loop, whose length changes are inter-dependent and depend on deeply nested function calls). The verification models that I have written in C++ and MATLAB use variable-size arrays, so I am quite certain I want to also use variable-size arrays in VHDL if possible.

Comment: There's nothing dynamic in your example top. Expressions (here a function call) depending on generic constants (the default class of a generic) are globally static (IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.4.3 Globally static primaries), meaning the value of internal_config_c is determined at elaboration time and not during simulation. The function is called during elaboration. What error message(s) do you get during synthesis? Without any output ports that are dynamically driven synthesis will not produce any logic. Without a better example are you describing an XY Problem?

Comment: The size of `data.all` is increasing on each loop iteration - this size change is what I am talking about. As I said, my question is not about synthesis. I know my toy example will not produce any logic. That was deliberate - to try to avoid unrelated discussion about synthesis, when I have a specific programming question about the VHDL language. Synthesis in Vivado 2020.1 fails with error "[Synth 8-27] allocator not supported [top.vhd:23]". I feel very confident this is not an XY Problem.

Comment: You appear to have discovered Vivado synthesis won't tolerate an allocated object even in a function called during elaboration to produce a value expression for a constant declaration. Recursive function calls are supported (UG901, 2020.2), what happens with the new function declaration style in synthesis? This points out you're not asking about a [specific programming problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), which says it is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Here you could find the length then populate the vector without allocation or recursion.

Comment: Recursion was the solution I already provided above. But, as I wrote above, "I would be keen to learn about any alternatives". Please feel free to answer the question if you have an answer.

Comment: *Is there a better way?* isn't a specific programming question lacking quantitative qualification. By what measure? You could pass the value of the constant as a top level generic including in Vivado synthesis and use the likes of C++ or MATLAB to generate the constant value. VHDL doesn't share strong domain overlap with either and as you've discovered can be further reduced by the subset accepted by synthesis tools (and Xilinx is expansive in feature support compared to other synthesis tools/vendors).

Comment: Ah, you appear to have missed the main question. It is in bold font above: `What programming constructs are available in VHDL (besides access types) for using (or mimicking) variable sized arrays?` This is the question and everything else is secondary to that.

Comment: The only other way would be to know the length of the whole vector in advance, and populate the bits by working out the slice ranges. The recursive form here is probably the least effort. VHDL has no "dynamic sizing" objects. Even for access types you need to know the length when you create the object. FYI - a null range bit string literal can be written simply as "".

Comment: You've covered both methods, (re-)allocated objects and recursion. You're at the mercy of synthesis vendors should you be targeting silicon implementation a major pain for something without any hardware impact as in your examples. Xilinx is positively liberal compared to the rest. [Recursive component instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49981526/declare-a-variable-number-of-signals-with-variable-bitwidth-in-vhdl93/50002251#50002251) (hardware description not programming language) requires any eventually determined length to be known in an outer declarative region.

Comment: @Tricky Thank you very much! In simple cases, I always do as you suggest: determine the length in advance. Sometimes this basically means running the whole function twice (1st to get the length, 2nd to populate the array). Or if I can at least bound to some sensible upper limit (then truncate), then I do that. And thank you for the null range tip!! My simulator was giving me an annoying (but justified) warning. Please feel free to submit this as an answer (otherwise I will do it and credit you).

Comment: @user1155120 "You're at the mercy of synthesis vendors". Never have truer words been spoken. This, sadly, is my life in a nutshell. Thanks for the tip about Xilinx being liberal - I will have to be very careful if I want my code to be portable.

Comment: They're the only synthesis vendor significantly supporting -2008. Who would have thought you could insure customer lock-in by adhering to a standard? There are also [constructs they claim as -2008 that aren't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66160847/assigning-return-value-of-a-function-to-multidimensional-arrays-in-vhdl-fails-wi).

Comment: @user1155120 I have only Altera/Intel to compare to Xilinx. Until 2018.2, Xilinx VHDL 2008 support was a buggy mess. It was much improved again with 2019.2. But up until this point Altera 2008 support was much better. Xilinx still have problems that their VHDL synthesis support is much better than their simulator, which seems rather disjointed to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best answer to this question has been provided by Tricky in the comments above:

> The only other way would be to know the length of the whole vector in
> advance, and populate the bits by working out the slice ranges. The
> recursive form here is probably the least effort. VHDL has no "dynamic
> sizing" objects. Even for access types you need to know the length
> when you create the object.